# Does the sequence sequence of bounded linear transformations have a supremum?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

This is an argument I used in one of the questions that I had in my Functional Analysis Exam.
I have a sequence of transformations $T_n$ from a Banach Space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$ where $T_n \in B(X,Y)$. I used the argument that since, $$T_n \in B(X,Y) \rightarrow \exists M_n>0 \hspace{0.15cm} s.t \hspace{0.15cm}||T_n(x)||_Y \leq M_n||x||_X$$
And since, we know that all these transformations are bounded, implies the set $S = \{M_n : \forall n\}$ is also bounded. And hence, it has a supremum $M$. Hence, $\forall n \hspace{0.15cm}||T_n(x)||_y\leq M||x||_X \hspace{0.15cm} \forall x\in X$.

Can anyone explain what is the flaw in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

What makes $(M_n)$ bounded? Take $T_n=nI$ (and $M_n=n$) to see where you are wrong.